# Javascript executed only on page refresh when included using <jsp:include>

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, oracle-adf

Hi I have included an html page into an adf jsff page using the tag `<jsp:include>`

```
<f:facet name="parenContent">
            <jsp:include page="www/included.html"></jsp:include>
</f:facet>
```

The page is rendered successfully, but the javascripts inside the included page is executed only on the refresh of the whole page (by manually refreshing).

**included.html**

```
<html>    
<head>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="grapheditor.css">
</head> 
<body class="geEditor">
    <script>console.log('loading page');</script>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <script>console.log("check");</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When refreshed the page the script tag is executed. The same is the case with javascript included using

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
```

I have tried placing the script tag in both `<head>` and `<body>`

I need to execute the js when the first time the page is loaded without a refresh. How is it possible?

**Update**

I tried giving a non existing path to the src in `<script>`

`<script type="text/javascript" src="thisFileDoesNotExists.js"></script>`

On the first load it is not even trying to load this file. On page refresh it is giving 404 error for this file.

Comment: Is what is expected to do, jsp tags are executed in server side, and javascript code in client side, after rendering the generated html.

Comment: @FranciscoValle Is there any way I could execute the js while the page is loaded for the first time.

Comment: Try to use this sintax: (function() { ...})(); inside a script tag. It will execute after rendering. THis link must be helpfull https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-t

Comment: tried that not working. None of the js is working untill a page refresh

Comment: Javascript is executed after rendering the page in a client. Is what is expected to do, if you dont attach javascript to events on client side it will not be executed again as html is not rendered again in browser. I dont know what result you are expecting...

Comment: I did the functionality by adding all the js resources in the main page. And is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call a javascript method on startup.

```
<af:document>
 <af:clientListener method=“nameOfTheJavascriptMethod" type="load"/>
<af:resource type="javascript" source="/customJsCode.js"/> ...
</af:document>
```

But I am not sure how can you prevent that from re-executing when user refreshes the browser.

Comment: What If it was In JSFF (task flow view ) How can We use Javascript in there?? .... in that we dont have af:documnet

Comment: @SaeedAreffard I tend to use an af:poll component in the page that fires only ONCE.